# Priority on Fitparameters

Tags: fitting, parametric-functions

I try to fit a function using the `FindFit` expression.

My problem is that `ZL` has to be `Infinity` so I just gave it a high numerical value `f0` has to be around `3.6136*10^9` and `0 < \[Alpha] < 1`. No matter how I redefine the values it does not fit correctly.

Is there a way to give the parameters `f0`, `ZL` and `[Alpha] a priority?
Meaning to give them a range or something like that, so that mathematica tries to fit the function changing the other parameters?

Thank you so much!

My code now looks like:

```
fitresult = FindFit[dbdata, Fitfunction[f], {{f0, 3.61369*10^9} ,
            {A, 300}, {B, -5*10^(-8)}, {ZL, 120000},  {\[Alpha], 0.1}, 
            {\[Tau], 1.73}}, f,
            PrecisionGoal -> 1000000,  Gradient -> "FiniteDifference"]
```

Cheers, Martin

Comment: It is not possible to say anything without looking at your data or function. And how incorrect is the fitting?

Comment: With `ZL` at infinity, are you sure the function works? Either way, you can declare infinity symbolically, with `{esc}inf{esc}`, and remove `ZL` from the fit paramaters.

Comment: You can add constraints using the form `FindFit[data,{expr,cons},pars,vars]`